# Asp.Net Core read appsettings value on program.cs combine DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings

I read the configuration from appsettings.json in program into my class so that through DI get access to the values in the controller. It works great.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var authSettingsSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Auth");
builder.Services.Configure<AuthConfig>(authSettingsSection);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
<...>
```

But then I needed to add the AddAuthentication settings to the program and I needed the values from the configuration. How can they be obtained in the program class? I don't want to write something like:

```
var key = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("MySection:SecretKey");
```

That is, it will be something like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var authSettingsSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Auth");
builder.Services.Configure<AuthConfig>(authSettingsSection);

var key = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("MySection:SecretKey");
var issuer = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("MySection:Issuer");
var audience = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("MySection:Audience");
// and more...

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(opt => {
      opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{
          ValidateIssuer = true,
          ValidateAudience = true,
          ValidateLifetime = true,
          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
          ValidIssuer = issuer,
          ValidAudience = audience,
          IssuerSigningKey =
              new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))};
    });
builder.Services.AddControllers();
<...>
```

How to read values both to the class and directly once without redundancy?

Comment: `var authConfig = authSettingsSection.Get<AuthConfig>()`

Comment: Also note that `var key = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("MySection:SecretKey");` is similar to simpler version `var key = builder.Configuration["MySection:SecretKey"];`